# Shortest way to create a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, shorthand

What would be the shortest way to do the following :

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'divClass';
div.innerHTML = 'Div Content';
```

... without any external libraries

Comment: Quod erat demonstrandum?

Comment: why the down votes? it's a fair question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Div {
    constructor(className, innerHTML) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = className;
        div.innerHTML = innerHTML;

        return div;
    }
}
let innerHTML = "<a href=\"this.html\">LOL</a>"
new Div(divClass, innerHTML);
```

This would be the shortest way to doing it again and again while still having some order inside your code, IMO.

Comment: Typically there would be an *options* parameter to set some or all of the many properties available, so `new Div({className:'divClss', textContent:'Div Content'})`. ;-)

Comment: There should really be a built-in basic JS class for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to do it in one line:

```
function tag(tagNameAndClass, innerHTML) {
    var parts = (tagNameAndClass || 'div').split(/\./g);
    var elem = document.createElement(parts.shift());
    elem.className = parts.join(' ');
    if (innerHTML) elem.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    return elem;
}
```

Examples of uses:

```
tag('div.divClass', 'Div Content') // <div class="divClass">Div Content</div>
tag('.class-one.class-two', 'Content') // <div class="class-one class-two">Content</div>
tag('h1.super', 'My Super Heading') // <h1 class="super">My Super Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the shortest way to do the following [...]

We can imagine a situation in which the `div` *already exists* in the DOM while the CSS style rule `display:none` ensures it remains absent from the visible document flow.

The following single line in javascript will make the element reappear into the visible document flow:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('divClass')[0].style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution I have came up with so far :

```
var el = function(type,props,appends){
    var el = document.createElement(type);
    if(props) for(var x in props) el[x] = props[x];
    if(appends) for(var x in appends) el.appendChild(appends[x]);
    return el;
}
```

and then when using it (creating a popup with header and body example) :

```
$title  = el('div',{className:'title',innerHTML:'Item Title'});
$remove = el('div',{className:'remove',innerHTML:'X'});
$header = el('div',{className:'header'},[$title,$remove,el('div',{className:'clear'})]);
$body   = el('div',{className:'body',innerHTML:'body'});

$el = el('div',{className:'item'},[$header,$body]);
```